# Entity is not removed from the database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core inside UWP Xamarin desktop app with a SQLite database.

When I try to remove newly created entity the `SaveChangesAsync()` returns `0`.

But If I restart the app, entity is being loaded from the database and can be deleted normally.

Here's my code:

```
    public async Task DeleteAsync(string id, TEntity entity = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity is null)
                entity = await GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (entity is null)
                return;

            dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
            dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;

            var rrr = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"DEBUG ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Always go to the DbContext to ensure you are dealing with the tracked reference. (Remove the optimization to pass an entity in, just fetch by ID each and every time) The issue is likely that after adding your entity the next call to delete it, passing that reference in, is not the same reference that this DbContext instance is tracking. You don't need the extra step of setting the entity state either, Setting state explicitly is a red flag, there are only very specific and rare situations it may be needed.